# Xamarin build base properties

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

What is the quickest way to get current Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Forms versions during build (binding/library)?

When building for Android msbuild reports current Xamarin.Android version in XamarinAndroidVersion build property. What are equivalents for iOS and Froms?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to get current version and build, I know two ways to do this, one is using Xamarin.Essentials to do this, another is using Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo to get info.

Using Xamarin.Essentials:

The first time you use the VersionTracking class it will start tracking the current version. You must call Track early only in your application each time it is loaded to ensure the current version information is tracked:

```
VersionTracking.Track();

 var currentVersion = VersionTracking.CurrentVersion;
 var currentBuild = VersionTracking.CurrentBuild;
```

Helpful article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/version-tracking

Another is to using Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo():

Detailed info for Android and ios, you can take a look:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-get-app-version-and-build-number-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was rather asking how to get those values during build not during runtime.

During the build time msbuild for Android gives XamarinAndroidVersion property but there are no similar values for iOS builds or Forms builds giving the current Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Forms version used for that build.

The one thing that came to my mind is to get this from Xamarin.iOS.dll (default path is available during the build) and parse packages.config for Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: @awattar, can you tell me why you want to get current version and build when you build project?

Comment: There are several reasons. The most basic one is to get this in build log on the build machine to validate what and when was build and what were the main assemblies.

If Xamarin.Android builds are capable to expose and print those most basic values the same should do iOS and Forms builds.

Comment: If you wish to use AppCenter, there is a way with a simple sh script that triggers during build. They made a great job on appcenter ! You can do anything with the pre build section for your script ?

Comment: @Umar3x, unfortunately, I'm currently limited to Jenkins. I reported this issue to MS - they are working on it https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/640098/xamarin-base-build-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way was to call VS/mono commands and examine related files:

```
vsVersion=$(/Applications/Visual\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/VisualStudio -h | sed -E -n 's:[^0-9]+([0-9]+[0-9\.]*):\1:p')

msbuildVersion=$(msbuild /version | sed -E -n 's:([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+):\1:p')

monoVersion=$(cat /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/VERSION)

xamariniOSVersion=$(cat /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/Version)

xamarinAndroidVersion=$(cat /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/Version).$(cat /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/Version.rev)

xamarinFormsVersion=$(sed -E -n 's:.+Xamarin\.Forms[^0-9]+([0-9\.]+).+:\1:p' $PATH_TO_PROJECT_PACKAGES/packages.config)
```